# R equivlent of python numpy slice: [:, None, :]

Tags: python, r, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

Given a 2x2 matrix `a`, convert it into a 2x1 array `b` where each column is a row vector from `a`. This is really easy to do in python. Is there an elegant and consise way to do this in R?

```
> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

> b = a[:, None, :]

array([[[1, 2]],
       [[3, 4]]])
```

In R I want this input:

```
a = matrix(1:4, ncol=2, byrow = T)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
```

to be modified to match this output:

```
b = array(1:4, dim=c(2,1,2))

, , 1

     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2

, , 2

     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    4
```

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you might actually be trying to get a 2x1x2 array?  So in R you'd convert the matrix to an array (these are separate classes), specifying your intended dimensions for the new array.

```
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, byrow=TRUE)
b <- array(t(a), dim=c(2,1,2))
b
```

Comment: A matrix is a 2d array, not a separate class.  Note that `class(array(1:4, c(2, 2)))` is `"matrix"` and `identical(matrix(1:4, 2), array(1:4, c(2,2)))` is TRUE.

Comment: Huh, I never noticed that before.  I guess I always thought of them as different classes since the functions that demand a matrix error when fed an array and vice-versa.

Comment: @doicomehereoften1, In python I can subtract the two arrays (b - a), but it doesn't appear I can do that in R this easily. In python `b-a = array([[[ 0, 0], [-2, -2]], [[ 2, 2], [ 0, 0]]])`

Comment: You might look into using `sweep()`.  I don't have to do a lot of matrix/array manipulation stuff since college so I'm betting you're probably doing this for homework...

Comment: @doicomehereoften1, I'm dealing with a machine learning context and I know python and octave, but find R to not be intuitive with linear algebra concepts. I'll look into sweep.

Comment: My apologies then. What algorithm(s) are you trying to apply? There might be a package that handles some of this fiddly stuff for you.

Comment: No specific algorithm at the moment, I'm just wanting to learn R's syntax for writing vectorized code instead of looping.

Comment: Cool, you might find Hadley Wickham's Advanced R useful then: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/  Also be sure to get familiar with R-Inferno, though it is getting a bit dated and not everything in it is true of the recent R releases: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf